# How to load a view which has a back button option

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm trying to recreate the way Notes(native) shows the back button for accounts. In my project I want to load a view by using the tab bar on the bottom, and that view to have a back button pointing to another view just like in Notes. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The use of a "back" button is default when using a navigation controller. You have a UITabBarController at the moment, just put that inside a UINavigationController then you'll have the navigation as standard. This will let you push and pop views with back buttons etc...

Comment: The problem is not in the UINavigationController, it's about how to change the segue from the tab bar to go to a second view(like in Notes, the application starts with the 'all notes view' and not the 'accounts view' which should be before it in the storyboard).

Comment: Ah, I've don this in the past by intercepting the "viewWillAppear" method of the first view and pushing to the second view without an animation. (Or possibly the viewDidLoad, can't remember). Either way, you have to push as the app opens. Then you're already on the second view and will have the back button.

Comment: Yes, do it in viewDidLoad. This only runs once when the app opens on the root view controller. Just push to the next view controller. Then your user can go "back" without having to go "forward".

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your UIViewController into a UINavigationController and then present that NavigationController containing your UIViewController. You should have a Navigationbar at the top of your View. If not, in your UIViewController, do:

```
[self.navigationcontroller setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

hope that helps